# OutOfMemory error with runOnUiThread and Flir One SDK

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-runonuithread

I'm trying to save the frame received on `FrameProcessor.Delegate.onFrameProcessed`.

If I try to use `runOnUiThread` inside the Thread that uses `renderedImage.getFrame().save(...)`, I get the following exception:

```
AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 25235166 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 20MB until OOM
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:278)
    at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:123)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.flushLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:358)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.appendLocked(FastPrintWriter.java:303)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.write(FastPrintWriter.java:625)
    at com.android.internal.util.FastPrintWriter.append(FastPrintWriter.java:658)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:691)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.append(PrintWriter.java:687)
    at java.io.Writer.append(Writer.java:198)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:324)
    at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:300)
    at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:527)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.Clog_e(RuntimeInit.java:61)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.-wrap0(RuntimeInit.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:86)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

This is the method that does the original thread:

```
private FrameProcessor.Delegate frameProcessorDelegate = new FrameProcessor.Delegate() {
    @Override
    public void onFrameProcessed(final RenderedImage renderedImage) {
        //Capture this image if requested
        if (imageCaptureRequested) {
            imageCaptureRequested = false;
            setProgressVisibility(VISIBLE);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd-HHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
                    String formatedDate = sdf.format(new Date());
                    String fileName = formatedDate + ".jpg";
                    try {
                        lastSavedPath = path + "/" + fileName;

                        renderedImage.getFrame().save(new File(lastSavedPath), RenderedImage.Palette.Iron, RenderedImage.ImageType.BlendedMSXRGBA8888Image);

                        toggleConfirmPhotoScreen(true, lastSavedPath);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }
};
```

The method that uses runOnUiThread:

```
private void toggleConfirmPhotoScreen(final boolean show, final String lastSavedPath) {
    //works until here
    Log.d("ExampleApp", "toggleConfirmPhotoScreen");
    ((Activity) getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //NEVER REACHES HERE
            Log.d("ExampleApp", "        " + show + " CancelConfirmScreen");
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see in the comments in the code, `toggleConfirmPhotoScreen` is called, but nothing inside `runOnUiThread` is, there is when I suppose the `OutOfMemoryException` occurs.

Answer (score 0):

put in your manifest
 android:largeHeap="true"